# Getting "Access is denied" error when executing pg_dump on Windows

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm trying to execute `pg_dump` for one of my PostgreSQL databases, but I am having permission problems.

```
C:\Windows\system32>pg_dump -U postgres -p 1863 -O social_sense > C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\8.4\\data\\social_sense.sql
```

I am getting the following error:

> Access is denied

Can anyone enlighten?

Answer (score 44):

I apologise for taking up your time. It was due to that there is no write permission to the directory i was writing to.

Comment: seems to happen fairly often.  I have seen some other questions to that effect.

Comment: Same permissions issue for me, thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: Weird why there is no permission to write in that very same folder... Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Or you can run the cmd as administrator. In my situation that solved the problem too. I know it is a bit late answer but I thought, it would help someone else maybe

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may get "ACCESS DENIED" because you specified the output directory but did not specify the file name.

ACCESS DENIED: `pg_dump -h localhost -d databasename -U username -n schema_name > C:\temp\`

OK: `pg_dump -h localhost -d databasename -U username -n schema_name > C:\temp\dump.sql`